# Ajax Adobe AIR and Facebook Connect

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, air

Is anyone aware of any *Facebook Connect* implementation for *Adobe AIR Ajax*. I know there is an Action Script (written by Facebook guys) but it seems that Facebook has forgotten about AJAX version for Adobe AIR.

Since Adobe AIR can't make calls via xd_receiver.htm would be quite usefull to have version written for **Adobe AIR AJAX** (not Flex)

Comment: You can do anything in Adobe AIR Ajax that you can do in ActionScript. (Well except extend classes, etc.) So if there is an ActionScript library, you should be able to use it from JavaScript, too.